# How to create application in the custom role account in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

I could create an application in an administrator account by the following step.

Setup-> Integration -> Manage Integration

I created one custom role and assigned to one newly created user. After logging in the newly created user account, there is no option to create application like an administrator.

How to enable or what permission should i set to create an application in the custom role account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per NetSuite documentation

> Only administrators and users with the Full Access role can complete
>   this procedure.

Please read the help topic `Creating an Integration Record`

Comment: I already read this. Thats why i am searching to create users with the Full Access role. I tried to create System Adminstrator role also based on Netsuite Answers. But i could not get that option(Application Creation). Is there any possibility to create role with full access like an administrator?

Comment: Administrator and Full Access roles cannot be created/customized, you can only assign it to the existing users, provided you have the license seats

Comment: Ok . Thank U So much Prasun.